What makes classical Rutherford model unstable?
Every reference to the classical Rutherford model of atom claims that it is unstable since the electron is radiating energy and so it should collapse into the nucleus.
But I had a confusion with the statement of instability. My arguments are as follows:
Basically the electrons are under the influence of central forces and thus its angular momentum ($|\vec L|=mvr$) must be conserved. So if the electron starts to come closer to the nucleus , the $r$ term starts to decrease but since $L$ must be conserved, the velocity should be inversely proportional to $r$ i.e. it must keep on increasing.
But we know that no particle with mass can exceed the speed limit i.e. $c$ . So doesn't it mean that the electrons can never collapse into the nucleus and the radius will eventually reach to a certain limit making the existence of stable orbits possible ?
Edit : As the answer and the comments pointed out, the angular momentum won't be conserved. Then can someone explain how will the speed of the electron vary as it falls closer and closer to the nucleus? And what is the maximum speed it can reach to?

Don't forget that the EM that an accelerating electron radiates doesn't just carry energy, it also carries momentum.

I have edited the question which might make the current answer not sufficient. So if the moderators want , I can revert back to the original question and ask a separate one.

Your argument is necessarily wrong because when the electron is radiating away energy, it would not be only "under the influence of central forces" and thus the angular momentum is not necessarily strictly conserved.
In fact, the fact that it is conserved, can also be used against classical physics.
@agaminon kindly noted that the particle experiences an Abraham-Lorentz force

To add to this, specifically the particle experiences an Abraham-Lorentz force.

Thanks. I'll add that to the main text.

Thank you for pointing this out. But can you then explain how the speed of the electron will vary as the electron falls closer to the nucleus ? Would it "hit" the nucleus before surpassing the speed limit ?

The atom in the planetary Rutherford model is stable, because the electron is moving in a central Coulomb field of nucleus, and for such field, stable orbits are possible, just like for motion of a mass point in central Newtonian gravitational field.
What Niels Bohr suggested is that the planetary model is too simple and does not take into account the fact that according to EM theory, the accelerating electron should radiate EM energy away. If we allow this, we are lead to the idea that an isolated atom, whose parts are not under action of external forces, should lose energy, the radius of the electron orbit should shrink, and the electron should eventually fall on the nucleus.
Conservation of angular momentum is not guaranteed then, but even if it was, this would not stop the collapse. In the shrinking atom picture, the electron indeed increases its orbital velocity, but not due to conservation of angular momentum (which may not be obeyed), but due to the fact the electron gets closed to the nucleus, and work of the attractive force being positive. This increase in speed does not stop it from falling on the nucleus. Just like with Earth's artificial satellite whose orbit decays - the satellite gets faster, but it still falls down.
This picture of shrinking orbit and the conclusion (collapse) is based on applying the usual concepts of macroscopic EM theory (EM radiation taking away energy as described by the Poynting vector) to the atom, arguably a problematic argument, since the Poynting energy expressions come from the macroscopic theory and are of limited validity.
However, much of Bohr's critique was correct; the Rutherford model is too simple because it is inconsistent with full EM theory, since it does consider that the accelerating electron has a radiation field. And when we allow for it, questions of energy balance and stability of the orbit become untrivial questions. Niels Bohr in his paper on this topic rejected traditional mechanical+EM theory model, and proposed that the electron can only exist on special stationary orbits, obeying some mathematical condition related to Planck's constant. In physicist's history of physics (not always necessarily correct), stability of Rutherford's model and stationary orbits are considered a big problem and a motivation for developing quantum theory and a better model of the atom.
